# How can i send sms notification to 200 phone number and subscribe them to a topic in SNS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, push-notification, boto3, amazon-sns

Hi Guys I have a use case:

I am a broker and post a load. When I post a load all the carriers in my fav list should receive an SMS stating "NEw Load".

I was checking through the Docs available, but couldn't find anything solid.

Steps:

1. Create a topic.
2. Add a subscription of the phone number to the topic.
   3.Publish to the topic.

I am able to create a topic:

```
import boto3

sns = boto3.client('sns')
response = sns.create_topic(Name='my-topic')
```

I am able to publish to the topic:

```
response = sns.publish(
    TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:region:0123456789:my-topic-arn',    
    Message='Hello World!',    
)
```

The issue I am stuck with is creating the subscription to the topic with multiple phone numbers.

```
response = client.subscribe(
    TopicArn='string',
    Protocol='string',
    Endpoint='string',
    Attributes={
        'string': 'string'
    },
    ReturnSubscriptionArn=True|False
)
```

I don't see if we can have multiple phone numbers subscribed to the topic.

Is there a provision to do this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Marcin No, I don't have a thing to implement multiple phone subscription. Don't know how to to be frank

Comment: To check the format, make one sms subscription in AWS console. then use [list_subscriptions_by_topic](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.list_subscriptions_by_topic) to check what are the actually values used. With this you can correctly set your boto3 code. For each phone number you will need separate subscription.

Comment: @Marcin so you're suggesting me to go through a loop of a single phone number at a time to create a subscription?

Comment: There is no API call to subscribe in bulk. Each phone number is one subscription.

Comment: @Marcin okay Marcin. Thank you for your help as usual a life saver. 
You can post your answer on this so that it will good for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

SNS [subscribe](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe) method creates a subscription for a single phone number. There is no API call to perform bulk subscriptions.

However, one can use basic loop in  python to create multiple subscriptions for a list of phone numbers.

If there is uncertainty of how `subscribe` arguments should be set, one can create a test subscription in AWS console, and then use [list_subscriptions_by_topic](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.list_subscriptions_by_topic) to check what is the correct form of arguments for `subscribe` method.